# How to use Netty to create a pipe to upload file to Amazon S3?

Tags: http, amazon-s3, netty

I'm using Netty 4 to create a server application that acts as a proxy to
upload/download to/from S3. I wonder if I have to use Amazon Java SDK to connect and send data to S3. I'd prefer to use raw Http(s) connection to S3 so that I could use Netty's low level network channel options to have better control. 
Any idea or example would be appreicated.

Comment: No, there's no need to use the Java SDK, as the entire S3 REST API -- exactly what every SDK uses -- is fully documented in the [S3 API Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html), including all operations and authentication.  In light of that... it's unclear what you're looking for, from us, here.  You'll need to review the docs for S3 and Netty and see if it feels like it's within your skill level, then give it a shot... then come back with a specific problem and an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @user3053227 I'm in the same boat. Can you share how did you accomplish it? I understand this question is very wide but any pointers on how to accomplish non-blocking streaming using Netty will really help me as well. Thanks.